# Is there a way to specify different Scala scapegoat versions for multi-project SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was trying the following:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps,
    scapegoatVersion := "1.3.5"
  )
lazy val foo = (project in file("foo"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.fooDeps,
    scalaVersion := "2.13.8",
    scapegoatVersion := "1.4.12"
  )
```

Each project's version resolved to 1.0.

I also tried `ThisBuild / scapegoatVersion := <some-version>` but it set the version for all projects.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible because of a wrong [reference](https://github.com/scapegoat-scala/sbt-scapegoat/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/sbt/ScapegoatSbtPlugin.scala#L115) to `scapegoatVersion` setting.

> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(crossVersion(GroupId %% ArtifactId % (scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild).value % Provided)))

The problem is that it adds `libraryDependencies` to `projectSettings` or scope `ThisProject` but uses a broader scope `ThisBuild` to refer to `scapegoatVersion`.

Because of this it ignores your `scapegoatVersion` specified per project.

Your approach would work if the plugin did the following

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(crossVersion(
  GroupId %% ArtifactId % (scapegoatVersion in ThisProject).value % Provided)
))
```

You could submit a PR to the [project](https://github.com/scapegoat-scala/sbt-scapegoat).